# Distribution issues on Bloomberg-enabled spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I've created a spreadsheet which *optionally* uses Bloomberg data pulled using the API COM 3.5 Type Library. I want to be able to distribute that spreadsheet to non-Bloomberg users, but they can't run it since they don't have the right libraries.

All blpapi-related code besides what's in the Class Module is behind if statements that should not be entered by the non-BB users. In the class module, I lazily define the session and Service so that the blpapi-specific definitions are delayed until the class initializes (see below):

```
Option Explicit
Private session As Object
Dim refdataservice As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

   ' First create session.
   Set session = New blpapicomLib2.session
   session.QueueEvents = True
   session.Start

   ' Then open service.
   ' A service provides the schemas needed to make requests.
   session.OpenService "//blp/refdata"
   Set refdataservice = session.GetService("//blp/refdata")

End Sub
```

In short - the code which appears to be causing the issues never runs. My (very limited) understanding of VBA is mostly functional, so I'm probably missing something obvious. Is this a compilation-related error? Is there a way for me to precompile the VBA so users don't experience this issue? Maybe some type of error handling method so the workbook doesn't hang?

Comment: For anyone trying to do something similar; this is breaching the data feed addendum. The terminal is a desktop solution and the data is not meant to be distributed unless you have a separate data license set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution for my own problem:

I had two functions with inputs that used library-specific types. I converted those to generic objects (using late binding on the session and refdataservice was not enough). Then, I unselected the bbcom library, and added a dynamic reference to the dll file in Workbook_Open(). Even if the load fails, the error is able to be caught, whereas before excel would have to be killed. This is still a problem if the user tries to use part of the workbook that uses the BB-related code, but this can be mitigated in a few different ways.